# How to conditionally skip Spring Batch step?

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-batch

I've a preconditions step, testing flow, and postconditions step. I'd like to skip testing flow if the preconditions step fails. Following the docs [Configuring a step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/step.html#conditionalFlow) isn't working, the testing flow gets executed no matter what. What am I missing?
Using Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE with Spring Batch 4.0.1.RELEASE.

```
val testingFlow = FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("TESTING_FLOW")
    .start(testExecutorDecider)
    .on(TestExecutor.JUNIT.name).to(junitExecutionStep())
    .from(testExecutorDecider).on(TestExecutor.GRADLE.name).to(gradleExecutionStep())
    .end()

return jobs.get(touchstoneProperties.jobName)
    .start(preConditionsStep())
    .on("*").to(testingFlow)
    .from(preConditionsStep()).on("FAILED").to(postConditionsStep())
    .from(testingFlow).on("*").to(postConditionsStep())
    .end()
    .build()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

```
val testingFlow = FlowBuilder<SimpleFlow>("TESTING_FLOW")
    .start(testExecutorDecider)
    .on(TestExecutor.JUNIT.name).to(junitExecutionStep())
    .from(testExecutorDecider).on(TestExecutor.GRADLE.name).to(gradleExecutionStep())
    .from(testExecutorDecider).on("*").end()
    .build()

return jobs.get(touchstoneProperties.jobName)
    .start(preConditionsStep())
    .on("*").to(testingFlow)
    .from(testingFlow).on("*").to(postConditionsStep()).end()
    .build()
```

TestExecutorDecider

```
class TestExecutorDecider(private val touchstoneProperties: TouchstoneProperties) : JobExecutionDecider {
    companion object {
        private val LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestExecutorDecider::class.java)
    }

    override fun decide(jobExecution: JobExecution, stepExecution: StepExecution): FlowExecutionStatus {
        return when (stepExecution.exitStatus.compareTo(ExitStatus.FAILED)) {
            0 -> FlowExecutionStatus("SKIPPED")
            else -> {
                LOGGER.info("Test executor: {}", touchstoneProperties.testExecutor)
                return FlowExecutionStatus(touchstoneProperties.testExecutor.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```